# Sending a change event from a jquery datepicker inside an asp.net user control?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, events, user-controls, datepicker

I have a jquery datepicker inside an asp.net user control.

I need to set up a change indicator (it doesn't have to be onchange, any event name will do, so long as I can reference it from the .aspx of the page containing the control to do javascript specific to that control on that page when a new date is selected on the calendar.)

This is the javascript to initialize my datepicker.

```
    calendarcontrol.datepicker({
        altField: calendarcontroldate,
        navigationAsDateFormat: true,
        onSelect: function(dateText, inst) { alert(dateText); },
        nextText: 'MM',
        prevText: 'MM'
    });
```

The datepicker initializes fine, and the alert does pop up on date select as expected when it is set up like above, but when I tried sending it up to the page by passing it through control parameters, or by calling the page's javascript function directly, it didn't fire at all.

What do I need to do to set up a control event for the internal calendar select, so that my page can catch it and do further javascript when necessary?  I have the control working beautifully, the final thing I need is to have an event show up on the page when a new date is selected in the user control.

Much thanks.  I'm getting better, but jquery is still pretty mysterious to me.

EDIT: ok, got it working like this:

```
    // init main datepicker
    calendarcontrol.datepicker({
        altField: calendarcontroldate,
        navigationAsDateFormat: true,
        onSelect: window[hfSelectDate],
        nextText: 'MM',
        prevText: 'MM'

    });
```

where hfSelectDate is a passed-in string for the function (I set it through the parameters so I can just use it in the aspx.)

Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add a `onchange` event on the original text input element. That event will fire whenever a new date is selected from the calendar or the date is entered by hand.

You can also use jQuery `change()` method to attach that event handler:

```
calendarcontrol.datePicker({...})
               .change(function() { alert('value changed'); });
```

Comment: The problem is not seeing events, that's easy enough.  The problem is forwarding the event out of the user control so I can get it on the page itself, where I invoke the user control for my page and want to be able to do page-stuff in response to those events (in this case, I want to copy that date down to another control.  Which won't be a problem if I can just get an event trigger to invoke the javascript to do so).  Internal to the user control, I see all the events no problem.  In the page itself, I get nothing.  Thoughts?

Comment: what kind of events are you referring to? ASP.NET postback events?

Comment: No, postbacks I can handle.  I need a jquery/javascript event forwarded, like when you get OnClientClick, so I can copy over with javascript on that page.  Only I need it to be the calendar's onSelect, preferably.  Or the onchange of the text box.  Either one, or anything else, but it has to be on the page, not stuck inside the user control.

Comment: `onselect: window.MyCalendarOnSelect` and then somewhere else `window.MyCalendarOnSelect=function() {}
`

Comment: That does work, but the problem is that I don't want to be stuck with having to create that function in every single page that uses the control everywhere (there are tons.)  Working on passing in the desired function (if there is one) to the init area, but so far no luck.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the way you have set up your page is biting you.Initialize your date picker in the aspx page as I have done in the posted link.If you initialize your date picker on the aspx page then you dont have to worry about sending anything ,since you will have total control on your aspx page.Your select function will be triggered exactly where you want in the aspx page and then directly do other stuff inside that function. No need of sending anything.

1.Attach a  css class to a textbox having the datepicker in the ascx control.

**ascx**

```
 <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
   <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" CssClass="myclass"></asp:TextBox>
  </ContentTemplate>
  </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

2.In the master page reference the attached css class.I have initialized date picker twice to take care of update panel.
**aspx**

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
        var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
        prm.add_initializeRequest(InitializeRequest);
        prm.add_endRequest(EndRequest);
        // Place here the first init of the DatePicker   

        $('.myclass').datepicker({
            altField: "",
            navigationAsDateFormat: true,
            onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {

               //here directly excute further javascript code.Piece of cake.
             .

            },
            nextText: 'MM',
            prevText: 'MM'
        });


    });

    function InitializeRequest(sender, args) { }
    function EndRequest(sender, args) {
        // after update occur on UpdatePanel re-init the DatePicker 

        $('.myclass').datepicker({
            altField: "",
            navigationAsDateFormat: true,
            onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
              //here directly excute further javascript code.Piece of cake.


            },
            nextText: 'MM',
            prevText: 'MM'
        }) ;


    }
```

[Example](https://www.dropbox.com/s/88vypoiphykspae/WebApplication3.zip?m)

Comment: The script had to work in the context of a single copy of the control on a given page, not the same way for all instances of the control everywhere.  It's fine now though, see above.  (And yeah, I did initialize like that, but internal to the user control, as the actual user control has 3 textboxes, 2 separate calendar controls, and 3 checkboxes, it's pretty complicated but super-nifty.)  Thanks though!